# Rollback all Django db transactions with middleware

Tags: django, transactions

We're upgrading a major django site of ours from 1.4 to 1.9. I want to [pull a github](http://githubengineering.com/scientist/) and use [laboratory](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/laboratory/0.4.1) to test the upgraded site against the existing production site. However, I can't have the new site writing to the (postgres) production database, for obvious reasons.

Now, I'll probably give this readonly instance readonly db permissions just to be sure, but I can't have it erroring on every write. It seems like I ought to be able to set the database connection in question to use `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True`, then write middleware to roll back the transaction at the end of every request, but so much has changed in Django's transaction handling since 1.4 that I'm not quite sure the best way to do implement that middleware.

How would I write middleware to reliably rollback every transaction, no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

The right thing is to set [AUTOCOMMIT=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#deactivating-transaction-management) rather than set ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True

> You can totally disable Django’s transaction management for a given
>   database by setting AUTOCOMMIT to False in its configuration. If you
>   do this, Django won’t enable autocommit, and won’t perform any
>   commits. You’ll get the regular behavior of the underlying database
>   library.
>        This requires you to commit explicitly every transaction, even those started by Django or by third-party libraries. Thus, this is
>   best used in situations where you want to run your own
>   transaction-controlling middleware or do something really strange.

So unless you commit everything, nothing actually get's into the database. If you use database backed sessions, you will need to do a manual commit there but leave everything else as it is. That would avoid any data in the live server being modified.

AUTOCOMMIT=False goes into the settings.py as follows:

```
DATABASE = {
   'default': { /* other stuff */,
         AUTOCOMMIT: False,
    }
}
```

This approach does not involve the creation of any custom middleware. It can be switched on and off quite easily.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll give that a try. One question though: if I'm not rolling back the transactions and not committing them, do I need to worry about them piling up now that Django also has persistent connections?

Comment: That one I really don't know but for testing purposes since you are not doing thousands of transactions I don't think it matters. BTW, you don't have to rollback manually.

Comment: I haven't gotten to it yet--other priorities came up. :) I'll check back once I've tried it out. Probably in a couple weeks at this point.

Comment: A follow-up question: if I use any manual transaction management (e.g. `@transaction.commit_on_success`) anywhere in my application, will this still work? Doesn't seem like it would.